# Getting all the details of a connected call through Twilio Studio as SMS

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I am using Twilio Studio to connect an incoming call to another number in an attempt to configure an IVR. I was able to configure the IVR. Now I am trying to get the call summary as email or SMS using the Studio widgets. I was able to configure an SMS widget and was able to send a simple text message telling that there was a call from the number. My Studio configuration is as follows:
[image: img1]
I have configured the SMS widget to send the incoming call details as follows:
[image: img2]

I need more information on that SMS, including call duration, if possible the call record audio or whatever I can. How can I get those values for sending as SMS

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You are getting the incoming call From number from the flow variable `{{contact.channel.address}}`, but each widget adds to the flow variables too.

Your `connect_call_1` widget variables can be reached under `{{widgets.connect_call_1.*}}` and from my testing you can get the following:

```
widgets.connect_call_1.DialCallSid
widgets.connect_call_1.DialCallStatus
widgets.connect_call_1.DialCallDuration
widgets.connect_call_1.RecordingUrl
```

If you start typing `{{widgets.connect_call_1.` then the Studio widget editor should start to autocomplete for you too.

Let me know if that helps at all.